# AlphabeticSort of Chinese character is not working now

Tags: sorting, character-encoding

I want to sort strings of chinese characters. I used to use below code

```
list={"大家","早上","好"};
AlphabeticSort[list, Entity["Language", "ChineseMandarin"]]
```

And it worked. But now it returns an error message

> AlphabeticSort::nalph: The alphabet Mandarin is not known or not
>   available.

What is wrong? How to work around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, under the "Possible issues" for `Alphabet` (which is used by `AlphabeticSort`), it shows this issue. Japanese does appear to work - if Chinese also sorts by stroke count, perhaps that's a useful workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following gives an answer (which I don't know if it is correct, not being able to read Chinese):

```
AlphabeticSort[list, Entity["Language", "Chinese"]]
(* {"大家", "好", "早上"} *)
```

I'm not sure why "ChineseMandarin" doesn't work.  Could be a bug in the translation layer from langauges to sorting order.

Comment: Great, works, Thank you : )